# Launching deep level activity

Tags: android

I have a main activity where user provides an input according to which i jump to a activity deep inside the heirarchy eg:
Let activities be B->C->D->E
 On user input it will jump from A to E.What i want to do is i want to add B C D onto the backstack so that when user press back button it navigate according to the heirarchy. Also i want to remove A from the backstack so after B app should exit. I know there are many related questions but I am not able to make out how exactly to do this. I have been following the tutorial for providing proper back navigation on android official site:[Create Back Stack](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/temporal.html). In this tutorial i did not understand how PendingIntent is used or what upIntent is.I am new to android development so any help will be appreciated.ThankYou

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to use fragments within 1 activities framelayout. You can use FragmentManager to manage the backstack

more info:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html